# What Does 'Share and Share Alike' Mean?

Tags: vocabulary

What Does 'Share and Share Alike' Mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to [what cindi said](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4487/what-does-share-and-share-alike-mean/4489#4489), The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms provides some background:

> share and share alike
>
> Mete out or partake of something equally, as in *Mom told the children to share and share alike with their Halloween candy*. This term, first recorded about 1566, alluded to the equal apportioning of spoils and soon was broadened to include equal sharing in the costs of a venture and other undertakings or possessions.

The Phrase Finder [adds](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/316750.html) that the 1566 cite is to be found in the comedy *Damon and Pythias* by [Richard Edwardes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Edwardes):

> Let vs into the Courte to parte the spoyle, share and share like.

It goes on to say that the first recorded appearance of the phrase using the word *alike* is probably this one from [*Robinson Crusoe*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_Crusoe), 1719:

> He declar'd he had reserv'd nothing from the Men, and went Share and Share alike with them in every Bit they eat.

Answer (score 3):

Share and everyone gets a piece. Share and share alike and everyone gets a piece the same size.